# Can we use Web driver to test https:// sites? I am trying to work on gmail.com and it doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class MyFirstSelTest {


    public static void main(String args[]){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");

        WebElement un = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
        WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
        WebElement submitBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("wp-signIn"));

        un.sendKeys("ValidUsername");
        pwd.sendKeys("ValidPassword");
        submitBtn.click();

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Gmail home page is opened, but no data is entered into username and password field. Can some one please help me as to what we need to do for this?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You **REALLY** don't want to do this.  GMail is a **HORRIBLE** application to automate.  I've heard from Google folks that even the GMail team finds it hard to do.

Comment: And yes, you can automate HTTPS applications with Selenium.  Of course, that's not what you're doing.  You said `driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");`, not `driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below locators.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.email-div>input[id='Email']")).sendKeys(Email);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.passwd-div>input[id='Passwd']")).sendKeys(Email);
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I do not get the problem is the submit button :

Try to replace with : `WebElement submitBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));` You didn't identify the submit button correctly.